# 400 bad request on admin-ajax.php only using wp_enqueue_scripts action hook

Tags: functions, ajax

I've been working on ajax lately. The tutorials you find on the net are all very similar and quite easy to implement.
But I always get a **bad request 400** on my `ajax-admin.php` file.

After a long and intensive search, I have now found out that's because of the time of integration.

If I use the `init` action hook to initialize script and `wp_localize_script`, everything works fine. So the code itself must be correct.

*my-page-test-functions.php*

```
function ajax_login_init(){
   wp_register_script('ajax-login-script',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/ajax-login-script.js',array('jquery'));
   wp_enqueue_script('ajax-login-script');
   wp_localize_script('ajax-login-script','ajax_login_object',array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),'redirecturl' => 'REDIRECT_URL_HERE','loadingmessage' => __('Sending user info, please wait...')));
   add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin','ajax_login');
}

if(!is_user_logged_in()){
   add_action('init','ajax_login_init');
}

function ajax_login(){
    //nonce-field is created on page
    check_ajax_referer('ajax-login-nonce','security');
    //CODE
    die();
}
```

But if I use e.g. `wp_enqeue_scripts` action hook I always get the bad request.

```
if(!is_user_logged_in()){
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','ajax_login_init');
}
```

The problem with this is:

I would like to have the functions in an extra php file and load them only if they are needed on a particular page. For this I need, for example `is_page()`.
But `is_page()` works at the earliest when I hook the function with the include into the `parse_query` action hook:

*functions.php*

```
function sw18_page_specific_functions(){
    if(is_page('page-test')){
        include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/includes/my-page-test-functions.php';
    }
}

add_action('parse_query','sw18_page_specific_functions');
```

So then functions hooked to `init` hook in `my-page-test-functions.php` file does not triggered, I suppose, because `init` comes before `parse_query`.

**Is there a best practices to organize this, so it works? Or how can I fix the `admin-ajax.php` bad request when using the `wp_enqeue_scripts` action hook?**

Comment: you can check this discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66464509/13278193

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think the only thing missing here is that you need to move `add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin','ajax_login');` outside `ajax_login_init`.

That code registers your Ajax handler, but when you only run it on `wp_enqueue_scripts`, it's already too late and `wp_ajax_nopriv_` hooks are already run.

So, have you tried something like this:

```
function ajax_login_init(){
  if ( ! is_user_logged_in() || ! is_page( 'page-test' ) ) {
    return;
  }

  wp_register_script('ajax-login-script',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/ajax-login-script.js',array('jquery'));
  wp_enqueue_script('ajax-login-script');
  wp_localize_script('ajax-login-script','ajax_login_object',array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),'redirecturl' => 'REDIRECT_URL_HERE','loadingmessage' => __('Sending user info, please wait...')));
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts','ajax_login_init' );

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin','ajax_login' );

function ajax_login(){
  //nonce-field is created on page
  check_ajax_referer('ajax-login-nonce','security');
  //CODE
  die();
}
```

**Edit:**

Now it's more clear that you only want to load the JavaScript on that particular page. This means you need to put your `is_page()` inside `ajax_login_init()`. I've updated the code accordingly.

Now, why didn't your solution work?

The `is_page()` check meant that your functions file was only loaded on that specific page. `ajax_login_init()` gets called and your scripts enqueued. So far so good.

Now your script makes the ajax call. As mentioned in the comments, ajax calls are not aware of the current page you're on. There's a reason the file sits at `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`. There's no `WP_Query` and thus `is_page()` does not work during an ajax request.

Since that does not work, `sw18_page_specific_functions()` won't do anything in an ajax context. This means your functions file is not loaded and your ajax handler does not exist.

That's why you need to always include that functions file and move that `is_page()` check inside `ajax_login_init()`.

So instead of `sw18_page_specific_functions() { … }` just run `include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/includes/my-page-test-functions.php';` directly. Without any `add_action( 'parse_query' )` call.

Comment: Good suggestion. I have changed that (still the same error), but the problem still is that the file containing the functions will load too late. But I need a way to distinguish which page is used. - currently I try this with is_page () as described above.

Comment: Are you trying to run `is_page()` from within `ajax_login()` or from within `ajax_login_init()`. The former can't work because it's in an Ajax context.

Comment: I have enumerated the files in which the functions are, as descriptive text above. The is_page() is used in the functions.php and serves to include the file with the ajax functions only when needed.

Comment: @Sin Again, `is_page()` does not work in an Ajax context. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to have the 'action' function name appended to the `wp_ajax_` tag.

```
function fetchorderrows() { // Want to run this func on ajax submit
  // Do awesome things here all day long
}

add_action('wp_ajax_fetchorderrows', 'fetchorderrows', 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

In case someone is using class based approach and having ajax 400 issue, you may need to move ajax handles outside class (try in main plugin file) and use class and method in second argument.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_your_handle', [ 'Class_Name', 'function_name' ] );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_your_handle', [ 'Class_Name', 'function_name' ] );
```

Comment: No need to move these outside the class. Just hook them to `admin_init`, so that they will be executed while managing ajax requests.

Answer (score -4):

just write die; at the end like below...[image]

Comment: Hi Zee Xhan. Welcome to the site.  Your answer needs some revisions. First, if your answer is code, don't post a screenshot. Instead, post the code as a snippet and format it as code (use the {} button). That's likely the reason your answer was downvoted and not accepted.  Also, a little more explanation would be helpful - like "why" just write die(), and where exactly does this go in relation to the code in the OP (original post)?