# How to create an ajax endpoint without js?

Tags: ajax

My question is fairly simple. I am working on a project that uses WordPress as a headless CMS(Kinda). I have created an ajax endpoint but it always returns 400.
Right now I have created a child theme to test these functionalities. Here's the functions.php that I'm using.

```
<?php

function login_with_ajax()
{
    echo "hey"; exit();
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (!$username) {
        echo json_encode(
            array(
                'status' => false,
                'message' => 'Username is required'
            )
        );
        exit();
    }
    if (!$password) {
        echo json_encode(
            array(
                'status' => false,
                'message' => 'Password is required'
            )
        );
        exit();
    }

    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = $username;
    $creds['user_password'] = $password;
    $creds['remember'] = true;

    $user = wp_signon($creds, false);

    $userID = $user->ID;

    wp_set_current_user($userID, $username);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($userID, true, false);
    do_action('wp_login', $username);

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo json_encode(
            array(
                'status' => true,
            )
        );
    } else {
        echo json_encode(
            array(
                'status' => false,
                'message' => 'Invalid login credentials'
            )
        );
    }
}

add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_login_ajax", "login_with_ajax");
```

I am trying to access it using fetch like this.

```
fetch('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ username: 'thewhitefang', password: '@bhishek01', action: 'login_ajax' }),
})
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: This endpoint will not be used in WordPress.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [400 bad request on admin-ajax.php only using wp\_enqueue\_scripts action hook](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291301/400-bad-request-on-admin-ajax-php-only-using-wp-enqueue-scripts-action-hook)

Comment: No, the request will be made outside the WordPress site. I have a react app that will use most of the backend from WordPress including auth.

Comment: One key aspect in the answer is that the place where the action is added is relevant. In the linked answer this was wrong - are you sure the endpoint itself is working and only calling it from your "non WP" script is the problem?

Comment: is there a reason you used the old admin-ajax.php API instead of using the modern REST API endpoint system at `/wp-json`? The REST API tells you what you did wrong in human readable error messages, `admin-ajax.php` just responds with `0` and no information

Comment: This is likely related to the use of `application/json`, something that is not an issue if you had used the REST API instead

Comment: @TomJNowell can you tell me how can I use REST API? Or point me to the documentation?

Comment: What content-type does the admin-ajax.php uses anyway?

Comment: there's an entire handbook dedicated to it with a big button on the homepage of the official WordPress dev docs

Comment: @TomJNowell alright, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using JS fetch api with the wordpress is set up your issue is with the body.

fetch passes body data in a way that wordpress can't understand.

Your body: {} should be like this

```
body: new URLSearchParams({
    username: 'thewhitefang',
    password: '@bhishek01',
    action: 'login_ajax'
})
```

and you need to change your content-type as well. `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

I can't really explain it well because i never really dived deep into this subject but im sure you could find everything you need about this.

Hope this helps =]

Comment: Thanks, It worked.